# nconf is not removing the values from the configuraiton file

Tags: node.js, express

I have a config file like the below one. I am trying to remove the `customLog2` value:

```
{
  "customLog2": {
    "key": "2",
    "value": "example"
  },
  "customLog3": {
    "key": "3",
    "value": "result"
  }
}

nconf.file(configFile);
nconf.remove('customLog2');
nconf.save(function (err) {
    fs.readFile(configFile, function (err, data) {
         if (err) console.log(err);
         console.dir(JSON.parse(data.toString()))
    });
});
```

I am still seeing the customLog2 in the file.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [nconf README documentation](https://github.com/indexzero/nconf#nconfremovename), the remove function is used to remove an entire "datastore" from the nconf object, not an individual key.

It is the opposite of the [add/use](https://github.com/indexzero/nconf#nconfaddname-options) methods.